# JUnit test failure | Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.runner.JUnitCore

Tags: java, junit

I know this problem has been posted multiple times before -- I did the research before posting here.  But I'm trying to run a JUnit test case as illustrated on this site:  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_environment_setup.htm

In the other posts on Stack about this folks usually say the classpath is the cause, so here is my setup:

```
ls -al /opt/junit/latest/
total 388
drwxr-xr-x. 2 dogzilla root       4096 Apr 17 21:00 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 dogzilla root       4096 Apr 17 20:12 ..
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dogzilla dogzilla   1499 Apr 17 20:59 hamcrest-core-2.2.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dogzilla dogzilla 381765 Apr 17 20:08 junit-4.13.jar

echo $CLASSPATH
/opt/junit/latest/:.
```

Here is the source code:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class TestJunit {
   @Test

   public void testAdd() {
      String str = "Junit is working fine";
      assertEquals("Junit is working fine",str);
   }
}
```

and

```
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;

public class TestRunner {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(TestJunit.class);

      for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
         System.out.println(failure.toString());
      }

      System.out.println(result.wasSuccessful());
   }
}
```

Then I run:

```
javac TestRunner.java TestJunit.java
```

and

```
java TestRunner
```

Which throws these errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/runner/JUnitCore
    at TestRunner.main(TestRunner.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.runner.JUnitCore
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 1 more
```

I absolutely am lost.  With the code from the tutorial, do the methods being called not exist?  I went to http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/JUnitCore.html and all the methods are there.

Why is this failing at runtime?

Comment: You have specified the Classpath incorrectly.  You need to read the Java command documentation on how the Classpath *actually* works.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html  (Hint: look at the section on wildcards.)

Comment: @StephenC ... It says, "Class path entries that are neither directories nor archives (.zip or JAR files) nor the asterisk (*) wildcard character are ignored".  My classpath is /opt/junit/latest/.  That's a directory, no?  If you agree /opt/junit/latest/ is a directory, then what is wrong about the classpath?

Comment: Since `/opt/junit/latest/` is not a wild-card, the JARs in it will be ignored.  It is explained by that document.  Read it again ...

Answer (score 0):

Posting the answer if anyone is having the same problem and comes across this post one day.  It was a dependency problem.  https://junit.org/junit4/dependencies.html

Cannot run hamcrest 2.2 with Junit 4.  Need hamcrest 1.3.